# Material UI - Stepper top and bottom labels with line

Tags: layout, material-ui, label, stepper

I try to make a stepper with Material UI (V5).
Here is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Stepper from '@mui/material/Stepper';
import Step from '@mui/material/Step';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import StepLabel from '@mui/material/StepLabel';

const steps = [
  'Step 1 - Top',
  'Step 2 - Top',
  'Ste^3 - Top',
];

export default function HorizontalLabelPositionBelowStepper() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Stepper activeStep={1} alternativeLabel
      >
        {steps.map((label) => (
          <Step key={label}>
            <Typography>Top text</Typography>
            <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </Stepper>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

That gives this result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHvlC.png)

How to properly position the line and the 'top text' labels?

What about aligning the icons with the line such as: [image with icon and line aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFLem.png)

Do I need to create a separated Grid or Box before the Stepper to create the top labels? Thank you.

thank you for your suggestions.

Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bellow I have the code you need including two solutions.

Solution 1 is faster and it will work better when the label-text of the steps have similar width between them. If not you have to specify the `.MuiStepConnector-root` `left` and `right` properties for each child if you want to have a better looking result.

Solution 2 includes a little more code and but will work no matter the width of each label-text. As it used a background color make sure to change it to match your background.

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-wiles-8sig7t?file=/demo.tsx:350-372) to play with it and see both working solutions.
Please make sure to comment or uncomment the code depending the solution you want to try.

**Code:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Stepper from "@mui/material/Stepper";
import Step from "@mui/material/Step";
import StepLabel from "@mui/material/StepLabel";
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";

const steps = ["Step 1 - Top", "Step 2 - Top", "Ste^3 - Top"];

// Solution 1
const StepperSx = {
  "& .MuiStepConnector-root": {
    left: "calc(-50% + 40px)",
    right: "calc(50% + 40px)"
  },
  "& .MuiStepConnector-line": {
    marginTop: "22px"
  }
};

// Solution 2
// const StepperSx2 = {
//   textAlign: "center",
//   "& .MuiStepConnector-root": {
//     zIndex: "1",
//     position: "relative"
//   }
// };

// Solution 2
// const TypographySx = {
//   zIndex: "2",
//   background: "#FFF",
//   display: "inline",
//   position: "relative",
//   padding: "0 15px"
// };

export default function HorizontalLabelPositionBelowStepper() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Stepper
        activeStep={1}
        alternativeLabel
        sx={StepperSx} // For solution 1
        // sx={StepperSx2} // For solution 2
      >
        {steps.map((label) => (
          <Step key={label}>
            <Typography
              align="center"
              // sx={TypographySx} // For solution 2
            >
              Top text
            </Typography>
            <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </Stepper>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: What about aligning the icons with the line? [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFLem.png)

Do I need to create a separated Grid or Box before the Stepper to create the top labels? Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my code and the codesandbox. You can add the `"& .MuiStepConnector-line": { marginTop: "22px" }` in the `StepperSx` styling. Let me know how it went and please consider marking it as a correct answer, thanks

Comment: Did the above code worked for you @MarcRichard?